# get the index of two elements and manipulate the array accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I build an array with the following code:

```
var intestColonne = [];
$('.tbi').find('tr:first th').each(function(){
    intestColonne.push(($(this).children('select').val()));
});
//intestColonne=intestColonne.pop();  //if this row is parsed the array becomes undefined
```

Now I want to check if there are multiple entries of a specific value in the array:

```
if(intestColonne.filter(x => x === "importo").length>1){
    //check the index of each "importo" element
    //store it into variables
    //remove all the other "importo" leaving only the first (lowest index)
}
```

I am stuck at the first step since I haven't found a specific function that may return all the indexes of the "importo" value.

`indexOf` will return the first index, `lastIndexOf` will return the last. Using indexOf I can specify where to start looking from but this will hardly satisfy my goal.

Isn't there another type of search I can use?

Comment: Why not eliminate the complex interior selector with this? `.find('tr:first th > select')`

Comment: @isherwood thanks, I learned something new. Also this way I don't need to pop out the last element that do not contain a select. It's not in the collection already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to get the indexes of the elements before `filter`.

```js
intestColonne.map((x, i) => x === 'importo' ? i : null).filter(x => x != null);
```

Alternatively, use `Array#reduce`.

```js
intestColonne.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
    if (curr === 'importo') acc.push(i);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .map() method to create an array of all the indexes of a specific value in the array. Here is an example:

```
var importoIndexes = intestColonne.map((value, index) => value === "importo" ? index : '').filter(String);
```

This will create an array importoIndexes containing all the indexes of the value "importo" in the intestColonne array.

You can then use the .slice() method to remove all the other "importo" leaving only the first (lowest index)

```
intestColonne = intestColonne.slice(0, importoIndexes[0]).concat(intestColonne.slice(importoIndexes[0] + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array filter method's second argument supplies index of an element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

So you can get index of first element using indexOf and then filter it:

```
const index = intestColonne.indexOf("importo");
const result = intestColonne.filter( (o,i) => o !== "importo" || i === index );
```

Comment: you are talking about the first element, I want the index of all elements